# Mini-Game Help 2- Executes same part of script after Raw_input

Tags: python, function

```
import time
import random
inventory = [""]
gold = 0
rawfish = ["Mackarel", "Cod", "Salmon", "Herring", "Tuna"]
trash = ["Old Shoe", "Plastic Bag", "Rusted Empty Box", "Plank Fragment"]
special = ["Copper Ring"]
mackarel_range = range(1,3)
cod_range = range(3,5)
salmon_range = range(5,7)
herring_range = range(7,9)
tuna_range = range(9,11)
oldshoe_range = range(11,16)
plasticbag_range = range(16,21)
rustedemptybox_range = range(21,26)
plankfragment_range = range(26,31)
copperring_range = range(31,32)

print "~~~~WELCOME TO FISHING~~~~"
time.sleep(2)
print "Loading Version 0.4 ..."
time.sleep(2)
print "In this current version the last item in your inventory is sold."

def sell_function():
    if inventory[0] in rawfish:
        sold = inventory.pop(0)
        gold += 5
        print "You have sold a", sold, "for 5 gold coins!"
    action_function()
    if inventory[0] in trash:
        sold = inventory.pop(0)
        gold += 1
        print "You have recycled a", sold, "for 1 gold coins!"
    action_function()
    if inventory[0] in special:
        sold = inventory.pop(0)
        gold += 10
        print "You have sold a", sold, "for 10 gold coins!"
    action_function()

def fish_function():
    if random.randrange == mackarel_range:
        inventory.append("Mackarel")
        print "You have reeled in a Mackarel!"
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == cod_range:
        inventory.append("Cod")
        print "You have reeled in a Cod!"
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == salmon_range:
        inventory.append("Salmon")
        print "You have reeled in a Salmon!"
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == herring_range:
        inventory.append("Herring")
        print "You have reeled in a Herring!"
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == tuna_range:
        inventory.append("Tuna")
        print "You have reeled in a Tuna!"
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == oldshoe_range:
        inventory.append("Old Shoe")
        print "You have reeled in an Old Shoe..."
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == plasticbag_range:
        inventory.append("Plastic Bag")
        print "You have reeled in a Plastic Bag..."
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == rustedemptybox_range:
        inventory.append("Rusted Empty Box")
        print "You have reeled in a Rusted Empty Box..."
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == plankfragment_range:
        inventory.append("Plank Fragment")
        print "You have reeled in a Plank Fragment..."
    action_function()
    if random.randrange == copperring_range:
        inventory.append("special1")
        print "You find a slightly dirty Copper Ring, after clearing the dirt it appears quite nice."
    action_function()

def action_function():
    chance = random.randrange(1,31)
    action = raw_input("Do you want to .sell or .fish?")
    if action == "sell":
        sell_function()
    if action == "fish":
        fish_function()
    if action == "inventory":
        print inventory
    action_function()

action_function()
```

I've already once asked for help with this game that I am still trying to make bit by bit.
So when I run the program, it seems to get to the `action = raw_input("Do you want to .sell or .fish?")` part it prints the prompt but then when I type either fish or sell it prints the prompt again. :s
It seems to me that it just goes back to the start of the function and restarts it.
Please help.

Comment: put an else clause to your long list of ifs, to see if you got an unexpected value. especially care for trailing newlines.

Comment: also you have lots of calls to action_function that should be indented one more level. i dont know if this is broken in stackoverflow or your code, maybe this already is the problem.

Comment: When I put an else clause at the end it says invalid syntax ._.

Comment: then you need to fix the mis-indented action_function calls first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `if random.randrange == some_range` checks. Actually, your code has several problems:

First, you need to actually *call* the `randrange` function, and it needs at least one parameter: the `stop` value for your range (which defaults to starting at 0). See [the randrange documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.randrange) for details.

Second, `randrange()` returns a number, but you're comparing its result to a list. This will *always* be `False`: in Python, `3` and `[3]` are *not* the same value. What I suspect you want is to check if your random value is contained in the list. One way would be `if random_value in some_range`, because the `in` operator searches a list to see if it contains the value you passed in. But this would be slow on really large ranges; a much better approach would be to stop using ranges and start using numbers marking the start and end of your range, then do `if range_start <= random_value < range_end`. Notice how I used `<=` at the start and `<` at the end; that's so that you can write your ranges as "from 0 to 2, from 2 to 5, from 5 to 11" (or whatever) and each possible integer will belong in one and only one range.

Finally, every time you call `random.randrange()`, you'll be getting a *different* random result, so it's entirely possible that your code would "fish up" multiple items, or none at all. Instead, you probably want to do:

```
random_value = random.randrange()
if mackerel_start <= random_value < mackerel_end:
    print "Mackerel"
elif cod_start <= random_value < cod_end:
    print "Cod"
    # Etc.
else:
    print "Nothing"
```

That should solve the problem you've been having with your fishing code. As for your selling code, it looks like it should work; the reason it's been doing nothing is because your fishing code was never adding anything to the `inventory` list, so there was nothing to sell.

**Edit:** One more thing. Stop calling `action_function()` all over the place; there's a much better way to do this. Instead of a long line of `if` statements, use an `if ... elif ... elif ... else` chain to ensure that one (and only one) of those will work. Then just let the function return at the end. And inside `action_function()`, use a `while` loop:

```
def action_function():
    while True:
        action = raw_input("Do you want to 'sell' or 'fish' or 'inventory' or 'quit'?")
        if action == "quit":
            break  # This ends the while loop
        if action == "sell":
            sell_function()
        if action == "fish":
            fish_function()
        if action == "inventory":
            print inventory
```

That will let you keep running the `action_function()` over and over until the user chooses to quit, then it will end the program. Much more elegant than having to hit `Ctrl-C` to quit.

By the way, I highly recommend reading [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/) as soon as possible, and going through the exercises in that book. Your skill at programming will be *greatly* improved once you're finished with that book. That, more than anything else, is the best thing you could do right now.